# SQLAlchemy: Join table with object's children

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have three object types with corresponding tables:

```
class Order:
  suborders = relationship('Suborder', lazy='dynamic')

class Suborder:
  ...

class PurchaseOrder:
  suborder = relationship('Suborder', foreign_keys=[suborder_id], lazy='joined')
```

Now I need to get all `PurchaseOrder` instances matching `Order`'s suborders. In pure SQL I'd write something like this:

```
SELECT po.* 
FROM purchase_orders AS po JOIN suborders AS so ON po.suborder_id = so.id
WHERE so.order_id = 'order-007'
```

How do I do it using SQLAlchemy? I tried this:

```
o = Order.query.get('order-007')
PurchaseOrder.query.join(o.suborders)
```

But this gave me an error:

> AttributeError: 'AppenderQuery' object has no attribute 'is_selectable'

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting required data with just one query:

```
query = (
    PurchaseOrder.query
    .join(Suborder)
    .filter(Suborder.order_id == 'order-007')
)
```

If you already have the Order instance `o`, you can do the following:

```
o = Order.query.get('order-007')  # already have the order instance
query = (
    session.query(PurchaseOrder)
    .join(Suborder)
    .with_parent(o)
)
```

, but you will still need to join on `Suborder`.

```
But again, the first one would correspond to the SQL query you provided as the SQL implementation.
```

Comment: I though of such approach. But isn't `.filter(Suborder.order_id == 'order-007')` somehow embedded into `relationship` type?

Comment: I do not quite understand the question. But if you do `print(query)` you will see that it should generate exactly the `SQL` you are looking for.

Comment: What I mean is that `str(o.suborders)` returns this: `'SELECT .... \nFROM suborders \nWHERE %s = suborders.order_id'`
So I expected to be able to join `PurchaseOrder` with the table of `o.suborders`

Comment: I see. No, it is not quite what you think. In fact, the only reason why `str(o.suborders)` even prints some kind of `SQL` is the fact that you defined the `suborders` relationship to be `lazy='dynamic'`. Otherwise, you can view is as a _definition_ of the relationship between two entities.  The solution I posted will give you result in just one `SQL` query. You can, of course, do it differently, and I will expand my answer with options.